# JDO getKey sometimes returns null after newly persisted ojbect

Tags: jdo

I have the same question that was never resolved at the link below. Has anyone solved this?

[Datanucleus JDO Retrieve newly generated primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021297/datanucleus-jdo-retrieve-newly-generated-primary-key)

Using JDO + GAE, after calling makePersistent, sometimes Object.getKey() returns a Key object and sometimes it returns null.

I'm using a transaction. I've tried detaching a copy, making the object transient, setting the defaultFetchGroup=true on the Key field and I still can't get consistent results where the Key field is always populated.

The documentation states the key field will be available after makePersistent is called, but this is only true sometimes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If used within a txn: with pessimistic txn any generated fields ought to be populated, and with optimistic txn they won't be populated til you call pm.flush(). At least that is the JDO spec. If used outside a txn then you have to wait til the makePersistent() is flushed (which it won't be til the next txn).